# ¿Porque NGINX me devuelve un error 404 al actualizar mi URL?

Tags: nodejs, nginx, gcloud

Tengo un problema con NGINX en una aplicación que trabaja con REACT, configure mi archivo nginx.conf, subi mi aplicacion a Cloud Run y me permite acceder a la url sin problemas

htts://app_cool.us.app/dashboard

por ejemplo si a mi aplicacion hago login y me manda al dashboard me deja entrar sin problemas, el problema viene cuando actualizo la URL -> "

> htts://app_cool.us.app/dashboard

" porque al hacerlo me da un error 404.

Este es mi archivo nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    server {

        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index index.html index.htm;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;

        gzip_min_length 1000;

        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;

        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        }

    }

}
```

y este es el error que obtengo al actualizar mi URL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]